# type of serialize in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array, I want to store it in a Sql table, so I'm using

```
$table_temp = serialize($table);
```

Let's say i want to store it in a field named "table" in MySql.  What type should this field be?

Comment: I suppose *PHP table* is a fancy name for nested associative arrays...

Comment: "champ" means "field" in French. Why would you name a field "table"? It does not seem very logical.

Comment: @Jocelyn - Because it contains a "PHP table" :-P

Comment: @jocelyn it was just an exemple of name, I want to store an array in MySQl

Answer (score 2):

First stop: http://php.net/serialize

There, we can read this:

> **string** serialize ( mixed $value )

The function returns a string, so we need any MySQL data type that can hold text. Next stop:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//string-types.html

Comment: thanks @Alvaro I've been to this page before, but when I'm trying, I have this answer "Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string"

Comment: That's unrelated to your question. Free to open a new question but I'll give you a hint: serializing a database object is useless--the object doesn't contain your data.

Comment: the type im using in MySQL is char(255)

Comment: thanks for answering, so you think I shouldn't serialize an array if i want to store it in a sql database?